# FadeIn Sticky Header

Tags: javascript

Using the following code to achieve a sticky header:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('header'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 200) {
    sticky.addClass('fixed');
    headerHeight = document.querySelector('header').offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById('main').style.paddingTop = headerHeight + 'px'; //.css('padding-top', headerHeight + 'px');

  } else {
    sticky.removeClass('fixed');
    $('main').css('padding-top', 0);
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

main {
  height: 3000px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main id="main"></main>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now I'd like to fadeIn the header when it becomes sticky. It should not just appear.

Comment: Please add your HTML too, in order for people to understand the problem properly and offer you the best help.

Comment: @Manish I‘ll add some html in a bit. But it‘s more or less just a header on a body that stays at the top until scrolling to 200px. At that point the header should fadein to be visible again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my example I using Bootstrap 5, like a quick start.

---

Using `position: fixed` Code snippet simple example:

Fade effect done by using `opacity` and `visibility` properties. `visibility: hidden;` used to make header not reachable if header invisible;

```js
const BODY_IS_SCROLLED = 'body-is-scrolled';
const HEADER_FIXED_VISIBLE = 'header-fixed-visible';
const HEADER_FIXED_PENDING = 'header-fixed-pending';
const HEADER_FIXED_PENDING_TRANSITION = 300; // CSS value of transition duration

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let isScrolled = false;
  let headerVisibleState = false;
  let headerHeight = 0;

  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  const header = document.querySelector('header');

  const checkScrollTopState = () => {
    try {
      const scrollTopSize = window.pageYOffset || window.scrollY;

      // toggling 'isVisible' state
      if (scrollTopSize > headerHeight) {
        if (isScrolled) return;

        isScrolled = true;
      } else {
        if (!isScrolled) return;

        isScrolled = false;
      }

      // applying toggle change to body
      body.classList.toggle(BODY_IS_SCROLLED, isScrolled);
      setTimeout(() => {
        header.classList.toggle(HEADER_FIXED_PENDING, isScrolled);
      }, HEADER_FIXED_PENDING_TRANSITION);
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn('checkScrollTopState E', e);
    }
  };

  const checkHeaderState = () => {
    try {
      const scrollTopSize = window.pageYOffset || window.scrollY;

      // toggling 'isVisible' state
      if (scrollTopSize > 200) {
        if (headerVisibleState) return;

        headerVisibleState = true;
      } else {
        if (!headerVisibleState) return;

        headerVisibleState = false;
      }

      // applying toggle change to header
      header.classList.toggle(HEADER_FIXED_VISIBLE, headerVisibleState);
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn('checkHeaderState E', e);
    }
  };

  const calcHeaderHeight = () => {
    try {
      headerHeight = header.offsetHeight;
      document.body.style.setProperty(`--header-height`, `${headerHeight}px`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn('calcHeaderHeight E', e);
    }
  };

  // calc header height on load
  calcHeaderHeight();

  // attaching handler to load and scroll events
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    checkHeaderState();
    checkScrollTopState();
  });
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    checkHeaderState();
    checkScrollTopState();
  });
  // recalc header height on resize
  window.addEventListener('resize', calcHeaderHeight);
});
```

```css
body.body-is-scrolled {
  padding-top: var(--header-height);
}

body.body-is-scrolled header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

body.body-is-scrolled header.header-fixed-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

header.header-fixed-pending {
  transition: opacity .3s ease, visibility .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<header class="bg-light w-100 p-3">
  fixed header
</header>

<div class="p-3" style="min-height: 1000px;">
  <p>
    Vivamus laoreet. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Nulla facilisi. Nulla porta dolor. Maecenas malesuada. Nunc nonummy metus. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada
    pretium. Nam at tortor in tellus interdum sagittis. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Phasellus gravida semper nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
    fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque egestas, neque sit amet convallis pulvinar, justo nulla eleifend augue, ac auctor orci leo non est. Nam adipiscing. Maecenas malesuada. Morbi mattis ullamcorper velit. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Vestibulum
    fringilla pede sit amet augue.
  </p>
  <p>
    Vivamus laoreet. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Nulla facilisi. Nulla porta dolor. Maecenas malesuada. Nunc nonummy metus. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada
    pretium. Nam at tortor in tellus interdum sagittis. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Phasellus gravida semper nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
    fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque egestas, neque sit amet convallis pulvinar, justo nulla eleifend augue, ac auctor orci leo non est. Nam adipiscing. Maecenas malesuada. Morbi mattis ullamcorper velit. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Vestibulum
    fringilla pede sit amet augue.
  </p>
  <p>
    Vivamus laoreet. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Nulla facilisi. Nulla porta dolor. Maecenas malesuada. Nunc nonummy metus. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada
    pretium. Nam at tortor in tellus interdum sagittis. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Phasellus gravida semper nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
    fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque egestas, neque sit amet convallis pulvinar, justo nulla eleifend augue, ac auctor orci leo non est. Nam adipiscing. Maecenas malesuada. Morbi mattis ullamcorper velit. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Vestibulum
    fringilla pede sit amet augue.
  </p>
</div>
```

In case you would like to use simple sticky header, you don't need to use scripts to make it work. It can be done by using `position: sticky`. To make `position: sticky;` work, you can use this part:

```css
position: sticky; // make block sticky
top: 0; // sticky offset (without this it won't work)
```

For more details take a look at comments in Code Snippet and [at this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

```js
const TOGGLE_CLASS_STYCKY = 'opacity-100';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // IntersectionObserver options
  const options = {
    threshold: 1.0
  };

  // IntersectionObserver observer
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
    const { target, intersectionRatio } = entry;
    
    target.classList.toggle(TOGGLE_CLASS_STYCKY, intersectionRatio < 1)
  }, options);

  // observer target
  const header = document.querySelector('header');
  // init observer
  observer.observe(header);
});
```

```css
header {
  top: -1px; /* 0 by default */
  /* top: -1px; fix for "IntersectionObserver" */
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- scrollable block -->
<div class="bg-primary text-white p-3">Not sticky block</div>
<!-- 
  sticky header;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* top: -1px; fix for "IntersectionObserver" */
-->
<header class="position-sticky bg-light p-3 opacity-25">Sticky header </header>
<!-- scrollable block (content) -->
<div class="p-3" style="min-height: 100vh;">
  <p>Ut tincidunt tincidunt erat. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Sed a libero. Curabitur blandit mollis lacus. Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo. Pellentesque dapibus hendrerit tortor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
    in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut tincidunt tincidunt erat. Vestibulum eu odio.</p>

  <p>Ut tincidunt tincidunt erat. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Sed a libero. Curabitur blandit mollis lacus. Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo. Pellentesque dapibus hendrerit tortor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
    in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut tincidunt tincidunt erat. Vestibulum eu odio.</p>

  <p>Ut tincidunt tincidunt erat. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Sed a libero. Curabitur blandit mollis lacus. Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo. Pellentesque dapibus hendrerit tortor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
    in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut tincidunt tincidunt erat. Vestibulum eu odio.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your suggestion. Nevertheless I‘d like the header to fade in after scrolling for about 200px. That‘s why I used the script.

Comment: ok, got it. Let me change it a bit

Comment: Almost :) Can you check my code above real quick. The header is visible in the beginning. You than scroll away until about 200px. At that point It should fade in and remain sticky, as shown in your example. It that's not possible in an easy way, I'll just use your "position: sticky" option :) Sorry for my missleading answer.

Comment: @Marzii I've made updates to make header fixed after 200 scroll and also added fade effect;